# How does function with no parameter works, while i'm passing arguments

Tags: javascript

```
function calculateAmount(p,r,t)
{
  function calculateSimpleInterest()
  {
    return (p*r*t)/100;
  }
  return p+calculateSimpleInterest(p,r,t);
}
console.log(calculateAmount(1000,10,2));
```

hey folks the above code executed successfully, but a newbie like me it still create a a lot of confusion.

Comment: The parameters passed to the outer function are visible and available for use by the inner function. That's how JavaScript works. It's called **lexical scope**.

Comment: please add the problem or confusion to the question.

Comment: There's no need to pass the parameters to the inner function for that reason; the inner function ignores its argument list.

Comment: calculateSimpleInterest has acces to the perameters of calculateAmount,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: `return p+calculateSimpleInterest(p,r,t);` == `return p+calculateSimpleInterest("foo", "bar", "quux");` == `return p+calculateSimpleInterest("hello");` == `return p+calculateSimpleInterest();` Those arguments would be ignored. They are irrelevant.

Comment: thanks all of you for your valuable input.